# map values in an array to values in another array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

please I have 2 arrays in the following format

`const images = ["image1", "image2", "image3", "image4"]`

`const items = [{quantity: 1}, {quantity: 2}, {quantity: 4}, {quantity: 1}]`

I need the final output to be like below

```
const newArray = [
    {
        image: "image1",
        quantity: 1
    },
    {
        image: "image2",
        quantity: 2
    },
    {
        image: "image3",
        quantity: 4
    },
    {
        image: "image4",
        quantity: 1
    },
]
```

Comment: Did you look at available array functions? Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to append a new data to the target object.

Working demo: https://replit.com/@kallefrombosnia/data-merge#index.js

```
const images = ["image1", "image2", "image3", "image4"]

const items = [{quantity: 1}, {quantity: 2}, {quantity: 4}, {quantity: 1}]

// Parse trough images 
images.forEach((image, index) =>{

  // Assign new item into target object
  Object.assign(items[index], {image});

});

console.log(items)


/**
[
  { quantity: 1, image: 'image1' },
  { quantity: 2, image: 'image2' },
  { quantity: 4, image: 'image3' },
  { quantity: 1, image: 'image4' }
]
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const images = ["image1", "image2", "image3", "image4"];
const items = [{quantity: 1}, {quantity: 2}, {quantity: 4}, {quantity: 1}];
items.map((e, i) => e.image = images[i]);
console.log(items);
```